# How to get selected text in Android WebView using reflection?

Tags: android, reflection, android-webview

I'm trying to get the selected text of my WebView in Android. I know Android does not let us to get this using the right ways.

One solution I've found in the internet is using reflection. This is the code I'm using:

```
    Region result = null;
    try {
         Object[] params = null;

         Method nativeGetSelection = WebView.class.getDeclaredMethod("nativeGetSelection");
         nativeGetSelection.setAccessible(true);     
         result = (Region)nativeGetSelection.invoke(this, params);
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But I am getting NoSuchMethodException. But the Android WebView has the desired method (nativeGetSelection). How you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView.nativeGetSelection%28%29)

So why is this happening?

Comment: You can't count on methods using reflection if those methods aren't in the official API.

Comment: What version of Android are you running this on? That method [doesn't seem to exist in 4.4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/webkit/WebView.java#WebView).

Comment: My minSdk version in Manifest is 13. I think the problem is the version, really

Answer (score 0):

Don't use reflection to get at private APIs. This will not work on Android 4.4 (KitKat) regardless of your minSdk/targetSdk because that API is simply not there.